# Why is $\arctan \left(\frac{\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2}t)-\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2}t)-t*\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})}\right)$ a line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, circles, osculating-circle

Why is this arctangent a line on the interval $t = (-1, 1)$

$$
\arctan \left(\frac{\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2}t)-\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2}t)-t*\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})}\right)
$$

I don't know of a trigonometric identity that simplifies this.

For context, I believe it is the angle between a point $x = \frac{c}{2}t$ on the chord of a circular segment with central angle $\alpha$ and the point on the arc $\theta = \frac{\alpha}{2}t$. I'm attempting to describe a circular arc/circular segment in terms of its curvature or degree of curvature rather than its center and radius.

Comment: It is not a straight line, however. Just close to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that additional $t$ in the end of your denominator is a typo, let

$$f(t) = \arctan\left( \frac{\cos(at)-\cos(a)}{\sin(at)-\sin(a)}  \right)\tag 1$$

where $a=\alpha/2$.
The addition theorems for numerator and denominator of the argument of arctan yield

$$\cos(at)-\cos(a) = -2\sin\frac{at+a}2 \sin\frac{at-a}2 \tag3$$
$$\sin(at)-\sin(a) = 2\cos\frac{at+a}2 \sin\frac{at-a}2 \tag4$$

so that the quotient (3)/(4) is just tan:

$$\begin{align}
f(t) &= \arctan\left(-\tan\frac{at+a}2\right)\\
&= -\arctan\left(\tan\frac{at+a}2\right)\\
&= -\frac{at+a}2 \bmod \pi\\
&= -\frac\alpha 4 (t+1) \bmod \pi \tag 5\\
\end{align}$$
provided we chose the remainder $\bmod \pi \in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: No, the `t` at the end of the denominator is not a typo.

Comment: In that case, the derivation is still approximately true if $\sin(\alpha/2)\approx0$, which might be the case depending on the choice of $\alpha$.

Comment: I'm using it for curves close to a straight line, so exactly when $\sin(\alpha/2) \approx 0$. Your answer shows what the angle would be at the endpoint $t = 1$ when the expression diverges.